# 404 error when use livewire route under localization prefix

Tags: php, laravel, localization, laravel-livewire

404 error when use livewire route under localization prefix !

when i write the route of livewire
`Route::view('/counter','dashboard.counterPage');` under the loczlization prefix and middleware i get an 404 error
and, when i write it above the them the code run correctly

there are the code in routes\web.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/
require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
Route::view('/counter','dashboard.counterPage');  #### the route the run correctly ####


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

// Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
//     return view('dashboard');
// })->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
    Route::patch('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
    Route::delete('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'destroy'])->name('profile.destroy');
});



Route::group(
    [
        'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(), 
        'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath', 'auth' ]
    ], function(){ 
        Route::group(['prefix'=>'/dashboard'], function () {

            Route::view('/counter','dashboard.counterPage');  #### the route that get an error ####
```

there are the code in Http\Livewire\Counter.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Counter extends Component
{
    public $count = 0;
 
    public function increment()
    {
        $this->count++;
    }
 
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.counter');
    }
}
```

there are the code in view\livewire\counter.blade.php

```
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <button wire:click="increment">+</button>
        <h1>{{ $count }}</h1>
    </div>
```

there are the code in view\dashboard\counterPage.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    ...
    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
    <livewire:counter /> 

    ..


    @livewireScripts
</body>
</html>
```

and when i tried to edit the file config\livewire.php and add
    `'asset_url'  =>  env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),`

i get an error in both situations.

this how the error look like when the route is under the middleware and prefix of localization
[this how the error look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F7pK.png)

so what the problem exactly and what i can do with it

Answer (score 0):

The `LaravelLocalization::setLocale()` method sets the locale for the current request, and it might affect the URL structure. In your case, the Livewire route might be conflicting with the localized URL structure.

**Define Livewire Route After Localization Middleware:**

```php
 Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(), 'middleware' => ['localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath', 'auth']], function () {
     Route::group(['prefix' => '/dashboard'], function () {
         Route::view('/counter', 'dashboard.counterPage');
     });
 });
```

This ensures that the Livewire route is properly localized.

**Check Route URL:**

Ensure that the URL you are accessing for the Livewire counter is correct after applying the localization prefix. For example, if your locale is set to 'en', the URL should be something like `/en/dashboard/counter`.

**Livewire Configuration:**

Make sure that your Livewire configuration is correct. In your `config/livewire.php` file, the default settings should work for most cases. You might not need to modify the `asset_url`. Remove the modification and see if it resolves the issue.

```php
 'asset_url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
```

After making these adjustments, clear your route cache and try accessing the Livewire route again. Run the following command:

```bash
php artisan route:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

In Livewire version 3 there is a solution for this problem .
the solution is using the Configuring Livewire's update endpoint

```
Livewire::setUpdateRoute(function ($handle) {
    return Route::post('/custom/livewire/update', $handle);
});
```

under the prefix and the middleware of localization. so the route will be like this:

```
Route::group(
    [
        'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(), 
        'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath', 'auth' ]
    ], function(){ 

        Livewire::setUpdateRoute(function ($handle) {
            return Route::post('/custom/livewire/update', $handle);
        });

        Route::group(['prefix'=>'/dashboard'], function () {

            Route::view('/counter','dashboard.counterPage');

        });
    });
```

and you can learn more about it
https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/installation#configuring-livewires-update-endpoint